# Inserting R variable in html a href tag in body of report

Tags: r

I am trying to insert a variable in the body of a r report so I change the variable universally versus every url in the report.

I have:

```
url <- paste("https://test.test.com/")
```

```
During the assessment time frame, <a href = "`url`"> high risk </a>
```

Comment: try "\`r url\`".

Comment: I cant believe I missed this, thanks!!!!